# Executing Spring Batch ItemReader in a loop and pass IN parameters

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch. I have following question.

I am using Spring Batch for developing a batch process.
I have a java array with some 'process_id' values in it. What I want to do is for each 'process_id' I need to call database stored procedure using a ItemReader. Can anyone help me to write ItemReader to achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think about your reader as designed :
The reader should provide the ID collection.
It will pass each ID to a writer that will call you stored procedure.

The goal of the reader is to find data to process.
Each data is then send to a writer (or a processor, depends on your batch design).